# Execution of thread groups in sequence but one after another . Times : loop count

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I am trying to run two thread groups and i want there sequence to be as follow :

First Thread group contains 3 http samplers and same for the second thread group and loop count for those are 3 .

Now the problem statement is : i want to run these thread group consecutively in the manner that first all three sampler of thread group 1 gets executed and then all three sampler of thread group 2 get executed . and then same thing should happen again in the above written manner .

Means i want this to get executed the no. of times same as my loop count for thread groups.

i'm attaching a screenshot for my test plan :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmE8Z.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGCmC.png)

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend going for [Test Fragments](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments) and [Module Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) instead, example test plan structure and output would be:

[image: JMeter Test Fragment Module Controller]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Under Test Plan, check the "Run Thread Groups consecutively".

[image]

Here is the sample output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jahan,  This does not solve my purpose in my casethreads are working fine consecutively but when i run them in loop then i want the execution to be like :   dummy sampler 1 to 3 then second thread group : dummy sampler 4 to 6 and then again loop for the same sequence. Hope i made it  understandable.

Comment: If you need still 2 thread groups, then follow the other answer given by Dmitri. But you can add all the samplers in one thread groups and just put the loop count 2. See the sample [output](https://www.screencast.com/t/3jKTcxw0jc). Thanks